# Cобственный класс в Entity Framework, ошибка: DbUpdateExeption was unhandled

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Не понимаю как использовать собственный класс в Entity Framework.
Что на данный момент есть:

```
public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyClass Node { get; set; }
}
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base("DBConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}
```

Собственный класс:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int type;
    public MyClass(int type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }


    internal object getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

Ну и использование:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDBContext())
        {
            db.Templates.Add(new Template { Name = "Имя", Node = new MyClass(1) });
            db.SaveChanges();

            var templates = db.Templates;
            Console.WriteLine("Список объектов:");
            foreach (Template t in templates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} - {2}", t.Id, t.Name, t.Node.getType());
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Но выскакивает ошибка. Даже не понятно, из-за чего она:
[image: Ошибка]

**Update**

```
public class Template
{ 
    public Template()
    {
        this.Node = new MyClass();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyClass Node { get; set; }
}
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base("DBTemplate")
    { }
    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Types<Template>()
            .Configure(ctc => ctc.Property(cust => cust.Node.type).HasColumnName("NodeType"));
    }
}
```

Вот

```
[ComplexType]
public class MyClass
{
    public int type { get; set; }
}
```

И использование

```
using (var db = new MyDBContext())
        {
            db.Templates.Add(new Template { Name = "Имя", Node = {  type = 2 } });
            db.SaveChanges();

            var templates = db.Templates;
            Console.WriteLine("Список объектов:");
            foreach (Template t in templates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} - {2}", t.Id, t.Name, t.Node);
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите например здесь [Entity framework](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/index.php) про примеры использования Entity Framework. а чтобы получить ответ/совет напишите более подробно что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: @Bald56rus Хочу, чтобы в базу данных можно было закинуть объект собственного класса

Comment: @tim_grayson, пробовали удалять базу данных перед запуском вышеозначенного кода? Вообще говоря, Вам `OnModelCreating` совершенно не нужен. Тем не менее интересно, почему исключение выскакивает

Comment: @ixSci Да, пробовал

Comment: Даже переносил код на новый проект. И можно поинтересоватьcя, почему мне не нужен OnModelCreating

Comment: А что за базу данных Вы используете? Если SQL CE, то скачайте расширение для студии SQL Server Compact Toolbox и сделайте script  Вашей таблицы - выложите его содержимое в вопрос. Если нет, то покажите что за таблица создаётся в Вашей БД.

Comment: а Вы нам Весь код показываете? что за NodeType колонка в исключении?! **UPD** увидел вы с modelBuildere Node переименовываете в NodeType, но зачем?!

Comment: @Bald56rus видимо из функции OnModelCreating. Больше неоткуда. Может solution куда-нибудь залить?

Comment: а вообще странно, все вроде должно работать если верить [этому](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/data/gg193958). и мне кажется ошибку **лучше** выкладывать текстом а не картинкой

Comment: @tim_grayson, в `OnModelCreating` Вы просто переименовываете колонку, как правило это нужно если нужно адаптироваться к уже существующей базе. Вам действительно нужно это переименование, или Вы просто скопировали это из кода по ссылке, которую я привёл?

Comment: @ixSci Может ли быть ошибка такая, если не хватает каких-либо библиотек?

Comment: @tim_grayson, нет, не должно быть. Я же Вам говорю, приведите то, как создаётся таблица в БД, после этого станет яснее

Comment: @ixSci я считал, что таблица создается автоматически, если ее нет.

Цитата> В этом сценарии рассматривается база данных, которой нет и которую создает Code First, или пустая база данных, в которую Code First добавляет новые таблицы. Code First позволяет определить модель с помощью классов C# или VB.Net.

Если убрать OnModelCreating, то в ошибке уже:
{"Invalid column name 'Node_type'."} а не {"Invalid column name 'NodeType'."}

Comment: @tim_grayson, да, таблица должна быть создана автоматически. Поэтому я и говорю - посмотрите, что там создалось в БД и покажите нам

Comment: @ixSci Нашел ее в C:/Users/Мое имя/.. в формате mdf..

Comment: @tim_grayson, похоже Вы используете SQL Server, я с ним не работал, поэтому не знаю как там посмотреть таблицы, но какие-то средства точно должны быть. Поищите.

Comment: @ixSci Не могли бы Вы написать код на подобие моего выше (использование собственного класса в БД), который ТОЧНО у Вас работает. Я у себя проверю. Потому что я делаю уже по 3 инструкции, даже студии менял. Все равно ошибки

Comment: @tim_grayson, я запустил Ваш код с SQLServer CE(System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0) и он отрабатывает правильно, вот результат: http://screencast.com/t/LDW4DOnA

Comment: @ixSci Странно тогда 8(. Ну ладно, спасибо Вам за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Чтобы посмотреть причину исключения, его нужно отловить и посмотреть `InnerException`. Разматывать эти внутренние исключения до тех пор, пока не доберётесь до сути. EF предоставит Вам необходимую информацию, в конечном итоге.
2. Вам нужно прочитать какие-то начальные статьи по EF, т.к. Вы, видимо, не совсем понимаете как им пользоваться. В частности, как Вы ожидаете, что Ваш класс будет сохранён в DB? Если Вам нужно использовать сложные типы, то посмотрите эту [статью](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx). Но, скорее всего, Вам этого не нужно, а нужно что-то другое, что из вопроса не ясно.

Comment: Я так понял, что нужно написать конфигурацию:

Comment: Сделал, как написано по ссылке, теперь InnerException - Invalid Column Name

Comment: @tim_grayson, отредактируйте вопрос - покажите в нём новый код и точную ошибку.